Custom Web API Skill input parameter name
I'm trying to call new embedding models from Azure openAI using Custom Web API skillset. My Json is defined this way:
{
  "name": "skillset-name",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
      "name": "Text Embedding",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "uri": "https://my_endpoint/openai/deployments/text-embedding-3-small/embeddings?api-version=2024-02-01&model=text-embedding-3-small&dimensions=512",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "timeout": "PT30S",
      "batchSize": 1000,
      "degreeOfParallelism": null,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "input",
          "source": "/document/representacao_vetorial"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "vetor"
        }
      ],
      "httpHeaders": {
        "api-key": "api-key"
      },
      "authIdentity": null
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

But when the indexer run, I'm getting this error:
Web Api response status: 'BadRequest', Web Api response details: '{
  "error": {
    "message": "'input' is a required property",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}
'

What am I missing? How to pass 'input' parameter to API call?

try with  "inputs": [     {       "name": "text",       "source": "/document/content"     },     {       "name": "language",       "source": "/document/languageCode"     },     {       "name": "phraseList",       "source": "/document/keyphrases"     }   ]

or inputs": [
{
"name": "text",
"source": "/document/content"
}
]

Ensure that the JSON payload sent to your Web API contains the input parameter as expected by your API. The error message "'input' is a required property" indicates that the Web API expects a property named input in the payload, but it is not being provided correctly.

Used the Custom Web API skill in skillsets  Azure AI Search .


 "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],

(or)
"inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "language",
          "source": "/document/languageCode"
        },
        {
          "name": "phraseList",
          "source": "/document/keyphrases"
        }
      ],



if using the field /document/representacao_vetorial exists in your documents and contains the correct data that you intend to pass as the input.
{
  "values": [
    {
      "recordId": "0",
      "data": {
        "input": "This is the text to be embedded."
      }
    },
    {
      "recordId": "1",
      "data": {
        "input": "Another text to be processed."
      }
    }
    // Add more records as needed
  ]
}





The documents should have an index before processing
{
  "representacao_vetorial": "This is the text to be embedded."
}


The indexer will extract the value of representacao_vetorial and include it in the input field of the JSON payload sent to your Web API.
